# How to concatenate column into one row based on CASE expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have the data below for example and I am trying to concatenate based on a specific condition:

```
ID      Amount       Account           Date
-----------------------------------------------
1        6000         G500           2-20-2020
1        6000         D800           2-20-2020
2        50           A950           8-20-2019
2        50           H650           8-20-2019
```

So for example based on the data above, the transactions under ID 1 within the application are under the same transaction record, so in this case I used the code below to concatenate.

I was able to use this to concatenate them into one row and now the results are shown below the code:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Account FROM acct a 
           WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND a.Date = b.Date
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') Account
FROM 
    acct b
```

Output:

```
ID    Amount     PaidIntoAccount       Date
------------------------------------------------
1      6000        G500, D800        2-20-2020
```

This works fine for the scenario above, but for ID 2, I would like to not concatenate them and instead somehow include a condition to the above statement to make it look like this for ID 2:

```
ID      Amount       Account            Date
----------------------------------------------
2        50           A950           8-20-2019
2        50           H650           8-20-2019
```

Currently with the code above, it concatenates ID 2 as well making it look like this below which is wrong, I need it to look like the above:

```
ID      Amount         Account                Date
----------------------------------------------------
2        50           H650, A950           8-20-2019
2        50           H650, A950           8-20-2019
```

This is because within the application, the two transactions for ID 1 are under the same transaction page, therefore they are one transaction but just with two different account numbers, so I concatenate these. Whereas for ID 2, within the application they are 2 separate transactions, but still with the same ID and date, so these need to still be shown on their separate rows instead of concatenating. The query I put above will concatenate both. How would I include the logic to not concatenate ID 2 in this case and leave them as they currently are in their separate rows?

Comment: Are you assuming that the amounts are always the same and that a "transaction" always consists of 2 rows and have the same date?

Comment: If they are separate transactions, yes it could be more than 2 rows with same dates but in this case I would like the outcome to be the same as well, for example if it was 3 rows with same ID, same dates, and each are separate transactions, then show those 3 rows instead of concatenating the Account. If these 3 rows were under one "transaction", then concatenate into one row combining each of the 3 Account values. Yes we can assume the amounts are the same.

Comment: I think you need more the filter to identify the data that need to concatenate or not. Maybe you can hard code the data no need concatenating.

Answer (score 1):

You  split them to two separate result sets and put `UNION ALL`

```sql
SELECT id,amount, date,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Account FROM acct a 
           WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND a.Date = b.Date
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as PaidIntoAccount
FROM 
    acct AS b
group by id,account, date
WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECt ID, Amount, Date, Account
From acct as b
WHERE id = 2
```